# c# creating registry key in windows 8.1

Tags: c#, registry, windows-8.1

I have a C# application where it writes an entry to the registry upon installation. This is to make the application start upon system boot. It works fine with windows 7, It adds the entry and the app starts soon after system boot. But on windows 8.1, it does not. It would e really great if someone helps on this. Thanks.

Troubleshooting done by me.

1.added the following in app.manifest with both highestAvailable and requireAdministrator.
`<requestedExecutionLevel level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />`
again this works fine in win7 whilst fails in win 8.1.

2.added the following in .cs file before initializecomponent()

```
RegistrySecurity rs = new RegistrySecurity();
    string user = Environment.UserDomainName + "\\" + Environment.UserName;
    rs.AddAccessRule(new RegistryAccessRule(user, 
        RegistryRights.ReadKey | RegistryRights.Delete, 
        InheritanceFlags.None, 
        PropagationFlags.None, 
        AccessControlType.Allow));
```

after adding this, the applications stops working and it fails to add the key.

Please help me on this. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably need `<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />` - `highestAvailable` tells it to use the highest rights without using UAE.

Comment: as i mentioned in the question, i tried both requireAdministrator and highestAvailable. Either of them failed to add.

Comment: Sure, just letting you know that you can eliminate `highestAvailable`. Anyway, is it possible you have a 64-bit installer and you're setting the 64-bit registry key instead of the 32-bit one?

Comment: Well this is new, i do not have any idea on that. im trying to set the registry key in CURRENT_USER (windows 8.1 64 bit). THe same code works for windows 7 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answer, i got it solved. Here is my solution for future reference.

I was creating an entry in CURRENT_USER, which was failing.
with permissions "requireAdministrator" in app.manifest, i wrote a code which creates a key in LOCAL_MACHINE. The app is now working fine in both win7 and 8 ( Thanks Matthew).